# Refactoring jQuery code to avoid the DRY Method

Tags: jquery

Its a to-do list and it works but I know it could be more efficient. What this is doing is toggling between input text box displaying or not and I'm also changing the icons.

```
$("i:first").click(function(){

    if($('i:first').attr("class") === "fas fa-plus"){
        $('i:first').removeClass("fas fa-plus");
        $('i:first').addClass("fas fa-angle-double-up")
        $('input').css("display", "block");
    }
    else if($('i:first').attr("class") === "fas fa-angle-double-up"){
        $('i:first').removeClass("fas fa-angle-double-up");
        $('i:first').addClass("fas fa-plus")
        $('input').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: i am not getting where you are repeating your self , except selecting element example ` $('i:first')`

Comment: Yeah, I actually meant more so a way of refactoring the code.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to *avoid* making this DRY? Code being DRY is a very good thing, and something you should always aim to achieve, not avoid.

I'm going to assume that is an error in translation and that you in fact *do* want to DRY this code up, otherwise I cannot see a point to the question.

As such, the click handler could be reduced to two lines using `toggleClass()` and `toggle()`:

```js
$("i:first").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-angle-double-up');
  $('input').toggle();
});
```

Also note the use of `this` within the handler to refer to the clicked element. This is another optimisation you can make to save having to query the DOM again to retrieve an element you already have a reference to.

Comment: Thanks Rory! I need to research some more on the toggleClass() because I tried it but I didn't add both classes in the same quotation marks so it wasn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple improvements you could make.

- Use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) so that you do not have to match the entire class string
- Consider using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add and remove classes.

We could then write something like:

```
var $btn = $('i:first');
var $input = $('input');
$btn.click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-angle-double-up');
  $input.toggle();
});
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using `hasClass()` at all..? Otherwise your logic is oddly identical to an answer which was already provided.